# Sencha Touch 2 - Execution order/priority

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am building a testscript that starts a timer, executes some random operations and then closing the timer and reporting how long it took to execute. This is what I got so far:

```
Ext.define('project.view.test', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'test',

config: {
    styleHtmlContent: true, 
    scrollabe: 'vertical',
    title: 'test',
    tpl: '<p id="time"></p>'
},
initialize: function() {
    this.measureTime();
},
measureTime: function() {
    var startTime=new Date();
    a = 2;
    for(i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        a = a*a*a*i;
    }
    var b=Math.floor((new Date()-startTime)/100)/10;
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = b;
}

});
```

The problem here is that I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

My guess here is that the html p-tag is rendered after the JS-code is executed. Is that true? I thought the script were executed operation by operation and the htmlcode is above the js-code which makes me alittle confused.

I've tried to put the javascript within the html/tpl tag (in the config). It removes the error but nothing is written out instead. Why? What order does everything execute and how do I fix this?

Comment: The docs on the `tpl` property say "**Note** The [data](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-data) configuration must be set for any content to be shown in the component when using this configuration." so it's possible that you're getting unexpected results because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to assign `b` value inside `<p id="time"></p>`

which your final result should look like this `<p id="time">0</p>` since your `b` value always being 0.

Firstly, give your panel an `itemId`:

```
itemId: 'test'
```

Then you can reference dom element of that panel using:

```
var panel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#test')[0].element.dom;
```

and set the value using `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`:

```
panel.innerText = b;
```

Btw, remember that since you're not using any store so `data` config is compulsory

Here is the demo: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#Y30Ul

Comment: Thank you. This was an excellent answer and deserves a big thumbs up! Well done, user1479606 and thanks alot!